# TypeError: null is an object (evaluating 'reactNativeImagCropPicker.default.openPicker')

Tags: react-native

```
pickMultiple() {
ImagePicker.openPicker({
  multiple: true,
  waitAnimationEnd: false,
  includeExif: true,
  forgeJpg: true,
}).then(images => {

}).catch(e => alert(e));
}
```

When i console.log(ImagePicker.opnPicker) it returns null 
  It doesn't call my camera is shows null is not an object

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check 2 things:

1. react-native library installed well
2. the right permission is given.

For the first, you may need pod install in ios folder after you install `npm install` or `yarn add`. You can find the git repo or the website for each module.

It is required right permissions for accessing to the camera or album in iOS and Android. If you get an error, check the permissions are given.

Comment: i'm using Windows not IOS, and i have installed the library and even linked it

Answer (score 0):

I change my library to `react-native-customized-image-picker` and did

`npm react-native run-android` Maybe you can use the normal one which is

`react-native-image-crop-picker` but make sure you always run build back to add

settings to gradle files and also run `react-native link <name>` then build project

that's how it worked for me